# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'. Specified method is not supported. At line:1 char:35

Tags: azure, powershell, csv

I am to bulk update tags on specific resources listed in a CSV file. But get the error in the title. Any Idea How I Can Convert to string?

CSV Example:

| ResourceName | ResourceGroup |
| --- | --- |
| vm10 | rg01 |
| vm11 | rg02 |

Code:

```
$ResourceList = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\43263\Desktop\resources.csv'

$tags = @{"DeptNumber"="123G"; "OwnerEmail"="virdi@mail.com"}

$getresource = Get-AzResource -Name $ResourceList.ResourceName -ResourceGroup $ResourceList.ResourceGroup

ForEach ($Resource in $ResourceList.ResourceName){
New-AzTag -ResourceId $getresource.id -Tag $tags
}
```

Comment: `-Name` is expecting a single Name entry, but `$getresource = Get-AzResource -Name $ResourceList.ResourceName` is presumably trying to pass it ALL of the ResourceName entries within that csv file as you're not yet within the `ForEach` loop dealing with them one at a time.

Comment: @KeithLangmead Thanks for that. I tried putting the variable within the loop but I am still getting the same error. Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over each row in your CSV and query each resource separately. Also, the property value you should use for `New-AzTag -ResourceId` is `.ResourceId` not `.Id`.

```
$tags = @{
    DeptNumber = '123G'
    OwnerEmail = 'virdi@mail.com'
}

Import-Csv 'C:\Users\43263\Desktop\resources.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $getAzResourceSplat = @{
            Name          = $_.ResourceName
            ResourceGroup = $_.ResourceGroup
            ErrorAction   = 'Stop'
        }

        $resource = Get-AzResource @getAzResourceSplat
        New-AzTag -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -Tag $tags
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**CSV File:**

[image]

Then used below commands:

```
$r = Import-Csv "C:\Users\\Downloads\emo1.csv"
$T = @{ID='0008'
 Name='rithwik'}
ForEach ($e in $r){
    $res= Get-AzResource -Name $e.ResourceName -ResourceGroup $e.ResourceGroup
    $x= $res.ResourceId | Out-String
}
ForEach ($v in $res){
    New-AzTag  -ResourceId $v.ResourceId -Tag $T }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]